# How to create json object and send http post in fiddleScript

Tags: fiddler, fiddlercore, fiddler-dev

how can i create json object and send pass http post method in fiddleScript
i try but not work

```
var sInput = '{"a" : 1, "b" : [2, 3, 4]}';
var json = Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON.JsonDecode(sInput);
```

Comment: "but not work" is a bad description for an error. Please post a detailed problem description, hence what you expect and what you actually get.

Comment: try `FiddlerApplication.Log(json.ToString());` what is the result?

Comment: i don't know how to create json object and send http POST sir do you have some example for me ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, aren't you suppose to "encode" instead of "decode" before sending ?